# Infamous Paper Trail cannot connect

Tags: infamous-second-son, infamous-paper-trail

Next to the mailbox it says:

> Connected to your online paper trail profile, checking status...

Then it just sits there doing nothing. I don't have a Playstation Plus membership but I don't think that it matters. Is there something I can do to continue?

Comment: http://infamouspapertrail.com/ is infamous paper trail. Set up an account if you haven't already and link it to your PSN profile. That's the only online paper trail profile I am aware of and the only way to check it from the game itself would be to link it to your PSN. Your "question" (I use the term loosely here), beyond needing proper capitalization, punctuation and spelling, is really hard to make sense of in general - if you don't clearly explain your situation, it becomes that much harder for anyone to help you.

Comment: Happening to me too it just sits there maybe wait there or go do something in second son and come back. check your internet connection

Comment: What exactly is he supposed to check ?

Comment: Im having the problem too. Most people are misunderstanding. We have already set our accounts and done some missions. I just put in my 6 digit code but now it says my next part is on the console but when i go there it just says checking status and it never ends and i cant go on...

Comment: @skovacs1 - you should consider making that an answer :)

Answer (score -2):

You must connect it to your PSN account.